# About Qt Creator IDE UI

Tags: qt

Please look the image below , I want to know what are the components of the three regions?

I think:

- A - is QToolBar + QAction
- B - is QListView
- C - I don't know what it is

Have you any examples to create Qt IDE style ?

Thanks.

[image: Qt creator UI]

Comment: List view and tree view, nothing fancy really.

Comment: Check Qt Creator sources.

Comment: its propably a custom widget, nothing from the Qt library. So either copy the code from the QtCreator sources or build it yourself

Answer (score 0):

You can use spy++ tool in the Microsoft Visual Studio ( any version ) 
That shows the class name of the window control by selected.

1. run spy++
2. click main toolbar -> log message
3. it shows a dialog
4. click search tool in top right and drag to the window control you want
5. see class name in the dialog.

Comment: do you know any tools like spy++ in linux?